# pseudo transient analysis issue

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice, transient

Note: pseudo transient analysis issue means that the LTSpice simulator is stucked with running pseudo transient analysis forever without any output waveform results.

The pseudo transient analysis issue happens only when I replace the OR gates (A5, A6, A9, A11) in favour of NOR gates inside the [ZD one-shot circuit blocks](https://gist.github.com/promach/38dbd308965b124de07bfad25d6e823d).

Could anyone advise about the [pseudo transient analysis issue](https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/software-tools/150272-ltspice-20.html) in my [GFSK demodulator circuit](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2982301_A_GFSK_demodulator_for_low-IF_Bluetooth_receiver) ?

[image: LTSpice simulation stucked forever]

[image: ZD One-Shot circuit]

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  Why "the schematic in fig 4 shows the wrong pulse polarity" ?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What do you mean by "cancel that" ?

Comment: My mistake. Regarding convergence errors, it is normally solved with smaller time steps on transients but I’m not an Lspice fan

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 using smaller time steps on transients also does not help.

Comment: I isolated the ZD one-shot circuit and then tried to ground the output of the NOR gates, but the pseudo transient analysis issue still persists.  Why ?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  I found a good way to debug this pseudo transient analysis issue.

Try increasing C1,C2,C3,C4 to 150pF and then changing either (A5,A6) or (A9,A11) branches to use NOR gates. 
Then the issue will be gone temporarily, the root cause is still under investigation.

Remember NOT to allow BOTH branches to use NOR gates.

Comment: I don't use LTspice. Probably would not have this issue on Falstad's sim.

Comment: I see you asked the same question in the [LTspice group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/a_gfsk_demodulator_for_low_if/80343092). By the looks of it, you were given told what to do. Did you?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I will use the advice, but the internal working mechanism of SK one-shot circuit is not discussed in LTspice group, explained well in the paper though.  Why does the circuit even need A12 and A14 ?

Comment: @kevin998x "*I will use the advice*" -- you should have used those advices in order to solve your problem, but it looks like you insist in asking "why isn't it working?" when you clearly were given what it takes to solve. Also, I'm guessing the reason why those parts are not explained is because the group is about simulation with LTspice, not design, which is what you're asking about. And the simulation part has been answered, in full.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen See https://github.com/promach/GFSK/tree/development , as well as the first and second points of TODO inside READ.md

Comment: @kevin998x Your passive filter does nothing, and that's a 5th order Bessel (or at least a 5th order). Do I see things straight: is the driver for the active filter an inverter with `100n` (***100 nano***seconds) delay?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen if I remove td=100n from A16 inverter, then the output voltage variation for bit `1` and `0` will be reduced from 425mV to only 75mV which is not robust for downstream receiver circuit to perform bit recognition.  One question, why would td of A16 affect the output voltage variation for V(out) ?

Comment: @kevin998x Let me get this straight: you added that impossible delay because your output is more substantial, despite the error? You have ~2 MHz *quadrature* with zero crossings every 1/2 T, or pulses every ~125 ns. 100 ns delay means 4/5 of bandwidth wasted, which can't be used in full because you can't have 100% duty cycle. So you're only using that because the output gets distorted and you consider that a useful result? This is an awful error (and thinking) and you should correct it, not use it. And your question is basic, you should be able to answer it. If not, this may not be for you.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen do you have alternative mechanism to increase the voltage difference for bit `1` and `0` of `V(out)` ?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I [removed the td=100n](https://github.com/promach/GFSK/blob/development/GFSK.asc)  and tuned some other components, yet I only have 150mV voltage difference.  What else do you think could be done to further increase the `Vout` voltage variation for bit `1` and `0` ?